# Why Array.prototype.sort() doesn't work in Chrome developement tool?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, ecmascript-6

```js
const arr = [{name:'Suzanne'},{name:'Jim'},{name:'Trevor'},{name:'Amanda'}];

arr.sort((a,b)=>a.name > b.name);
```

I want to sort elements(objects) in the array name-alphabetically(A->Z). When I use the code in node(v8.4.0) and safari development tool(console), it works well.

But it doesn't work in chrome development tool-console(v70.0.3538.110). There is a result of code in chrome console.

[image]

In my opinion, the code is not wrong. I don't know why the code doesn't work well.

Comment: `When I use the code in node(v8.4.0) and safari development tool(console), it works well.` That's interesting, since the sort method expects a callback returning a **number**, and the above expression is returning a **boolean**. The code is **not** correct or, at least, your code is not supposed to what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, briosheje. I thought callback of sort method can return **boolean**. But that's wrong. Safari console and node are weird...;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.sort()` callback must return a **number**, not a boolean. The return value should be:

- a negative number if the first element should go *before* the second;
- a positive number if the first element should go *after* the second;
- zero if the two elements are ordered the same.

For strings, you can use the `.localeCompare()` method:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

Comment: Thanks! But that means node and safari console are wrong(or don't follow to ECMAScript standard). Because the code is wrong, but they work well..:(

Comment: @eje well a "wrong" sort comparator can *sometimes* work; it depends on very specific details of the sort algorithm.

Comment: Thanks to you Pointy, I got to know something new.